# example of increasing size weakening security?

Tags: encryption

I'm seeking an example of a cipher construction with two variants differing by key/block/state size yet sharing most of the internal structure. Where the larger varient is easier to break than the smaller version.
Should be clearly related to a well known cipher so that claiming strength of smaller varient will have merit. Bonus points for increasing also key size not just block/state.
I'm aware of how this could happen, just looking for an example where it does.

Comment: Isn't there a related-key attack against AES-256 that makes it much worse than AES-128 (but only in a highly unrealistic scenario since, well, it's a related-key attack)?

Comment: [This is the paper Gilles was talking about, where AES-256 has "much less security" than the other two standardized variants.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/317)